# Is there a way to use map-like syntax for setting variables in non-map code blocks in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am often writing code where I want to evaluate an expression and then pass the result of that expression down to the next block of code as a variable using syntax similar to that used with a map or fold expression.

The sort of code that I want to write would look something like we do with an Option or Future:

```
Some("foo") map { upper => s"works with $upper"}
```

but without objects that support map.

A good example (but not the only one) is doing replacement of Json elements in with the spray libraries. Something like:

```
JsObject(upper.fields +
  ("obj" -> JsObject(
    upper.fields("obj").asJsObject { lower: JsObject => lower.fields +
      ("data" -> JsObject(lower.fields("data")))
    }
  ))
)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without resorting to nesting matches?

Answer 1: Here is an example using the mouse library with Scala 2.12:

```
def withMouse(upper: JsObject): JsObject = {
  upper
    .|> { upper => println(upper.compactPrint); upper.fields; }
    .|> { upper => upper + ("obj" ->
      upper("obj").asJsObject.fields
        .|> { lower => JsObject(lower + ("data" ->
          lower("data")
        ))}
    )}
    .|> { newmsg => JsObject(newmsg) }
}
```

Answer 2: Here is the same example using the [ChainingOps](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/ChainingOps.html) library's .pipe method with Scala 2.13

```
def withPipe(upper: JsObject): JsObject = {
  upper
    .pipe { upper => println(upper.compactPrint); upper.fields; }
    .pipe { upper => upper + ("obj" ->
      upper("obj").asJsObject.fields
        .pipe { lower => JsObject(lower + ("data" ->
          lower("data")
        ))}
    )}
    .pipe { newmsg => JsObject(newmsg) }
}
```

Comment: Thank @texasbruce. Working with chained (and nested) matches, I find the compiler is finicky about using () to wrap the matches. The tightest code that I can get using matches is: ```def withMatch(upper: JsObject): JsObject = {
  ((upper match { case upper => upper.fields })
    match { case upperf => {
      upperf +
        ("obj" ->
          (upperf("obj").asJsObject.fields match {
            case lower => JsObject(lower + ("data" -> lower("data")))
          })
        )
    }})
  match { case newmsg => JsObject(newmsg) }
}``` See anything you would do differently?

Comment: You are right the brackets are needed. It's not a pretty solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not on Scala 2.13, there exists [`mouse`](https://github.com/typelevel/mouse) which provides similar chaining operators, for example,

```
input
  .<|     { println        }
  .<|     { preconditions  }
  .thrush { program        }
  .<|     { postconditions }
  .<|     { println        }
```

where

```
import mouse.all._
import scala.io.StdIn

case class User(name: String, age: Int, previous: Option[User] = None) {
  def changeName(newName: String): User =
    this.copy(name = newName, previous = Some(this))
}

def preconditions(user: User): Unit = {
  assert(user.name.nonEmpty, "User should have a name")
  assert(user.age >= 0, "User's age should not be negative")
}

def postconditions(`new`: User): Unit = {
  assert(
    `new`.previous.exists(_.name != `new`.name),
    "User should have changed their name details"
  )
}

def program(user: User): User = {
  println(s"Please enter new name for $user")
  val newName = StdIn.readLine()
  user.changeName(newName)
}

val input = User("Picard", 75)
```

Note how `<|` just executes side-effect, whilst `thrush` may transform.

Comment: Thanks, Mario. I am running Scala 2.12 in this current project so it is helpful. I see from https://github.com/typelevel/mouse/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/mouse/any.scala that .|> and .thrush are interchangeable. This syntax resembles my beloved for comprehensions. I will post an example in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want `pipe()`.

From the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/ChainingOps.html):

```
import scala.util.chaining._

val times6 = (_: Int) * 6
//times6: Int => Int = $$Lambda$2023/975629453@17143b3b

val i = (1 - 2 - 3).pipe(times6).pipe(scala.math.abs)
//i: Int = 24
```

Comment: I prefer using core language capabilities. Pipe and Tap look like they will work the way that I am expecting. I haven't been able to get worksheets work properly for 2.13.2 yet, so I cannot prototype it properly. But I will post what should be a working example in my question. Thanks, @jwvh!